# Is there any way to save data on my own website using a flutter webapp?

Tags: flutter, dart, web, flutter-web

I want to use my flutter webapp to save data on my website (without using firebase or any third party database). For example, if one user triggers a save function in the webapp on one computer, another user can read that data using the webapp on another computer.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @JediBurrell I'm not using a database, I plan on just having one app place a text document inside the website subdirectory, while the other reads it. The reading part works, I just don't know how to create a file and place it inside said subdir using a flutter webapp